# What edits should I make to my code for it to print as expected

Tags: java, function, class

I'm trying to write a function `myMethod` that will print a pattern like this based on what the input `k` is:

In this case `k` = 7

```
#######
######
#####
####
###
##
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

However, I'm struggling to understand what modifications I'm supposed to do with my code in order for it to run.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Diamond {
    static void myMethod(int k) {
        for (int j = -k; j <= k; j++) {
            String m = "#";
            System.out.println((m.repeat(Math.abs(j))));
    }

    public static void main(Integer[]) {
        myMethod(9);
    }}

}
```

I am unable to run my code due to errors in placing `(` and `;`, however, even when I have added or remove tge `(` and `;`, the error still remains.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "I am unable to run my code due to errors in placing ( and ;... What am I doing wrong here?" Well, maybe what you are doing wrong is putting `(` and `;` (and `)`) in the wrong place(s)? "however, even when I have added or remove tge `(` and `;`, the error still remains." Do you understand what they are for? Did you **try to think** about where they should go? What exactly do you find confusing about it? (I think one of your errors is about the placement of `}`, actually.) Please read [ask]; note that this is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `jdk` version is lower than `JDK 11`,we can use below code

```
    int k = 7;
    for (int j = -k; j <= k; j++) {
        String m = "#";
        int abs = Math.abs(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < abs; i++) {
            System.out.print(m);
        }
        if (abs > 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Otherwise

```
    int k = 7;
    for (int j = -k; j <= k; j++) {
        String m = "#";
        int abs = Math.abs(j);                
        System.out.println(m.repeat(abs));
    }
```